# Using dots in a MySQL database - updating using node

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm trying to update a column name that contains a dot in node using node-mysql. I love how you can easily update multiple columns by just giving it an object with keys, but the escaping of the strings by node-mysql is failing here.

This is my code:

```
socket.on('settings',function(data){
    console.log(data);
    database.query('UPDATE Settings SET ? WHERE ?',[data,{name:socket.name}],function(err,rows){
        if(err) console.log(err);
    });
});
```

When this event fires with data = {'a.b':'hello'}, it gives me the following error:

```
{ [Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
''`a`.`b` = 'hello'' WHERE `name` = 'somename'' at line 1]
```

I know not using dots in my column name fixes my problem, but I'd **really** like them to be there.

**EDIT:** It seems that using 'a.b' as a column name gives me ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR, same with 'a.b.c', even when they're in the table, but when I use 'a.b.c.d' it says ER_PARSE_ERROR. I'm so confused. I won't be using dots in my column names, but I'd still like to know why it would generate different errors with varying amounts of dots.

Comment: What if you try to escape the dots with \\.

Comment: Alright. I narrowed my problem down. It finds the column name (if i test it with column names not in the table, I get the UNKNOWN_COLUMN_NAME error. here i'm getting the ER_PARSE_ERROR error, which means there's something wrong with my query. I'll take another look at it.

Comment: I edited my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Notations like in error message:

```
`a`.`b`
```

Means "current_database" (if a is not database name) -> "table with name 'a'" -> "column with name 'b'". So if whant to use dot within column name you should qoute it whole with backticks:

```
UPDATE table_name.`a.b` = 'hello' WHERE `name` = 'somename';
```

By the way, I prefer to use double underscore notation instead of dot (a__b) for not qouting with backtiks, just think about it.